# Sufficient (and necessary?) conditions for normality of Gaussian process integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

### Question

Let $X(\cdot)$ be a Gaussian process on $\mathcal{J}=[a,b]\subseteq\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ (extended real line) with mean $\theta(\cdot)$ and covariance $\Sigma(\cdot,\cdot)$.  My goal is to find sufficient conditions on $\mathcal{J}$ and $\rho(\cdot)$ such that
\begin{gather*}
\int_\mathcal{J} X(j)\,d\rho(j) \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2), \\
\mu = \int_\mathcal{J}\theta(j)\,d\rho(j) , \quad
\sigma^2 = \int_\mathcal{J} \int_\mathcal{J} \Sigma(i,j)\,d\rho(i)\,d\rho(j) . 
\end{gather*}
As usual, I'd like these sufficient conditions to be as weak as possible (ideally necessary).  One exception is that it's fine to directly assume $0<\sigma^2<\infty$.  Ideally, such results/conditions already exist in a paper or book, in which case I just need the reference.

EDIT: for my purpose, it's fine to assume continuous sample paths and a continuous covariance function.

---

### Context and current best attempt

In the bigger picture: I know $\theta(\cdot)$ is in some function space (over $\mathcal{J}$ with Lebesgue measure), but I don't know which (e.g., maybe sometimes $L^2$, sometimes continuous bounded functions, etc.).  I want to know whether for any bounded linear functional $f(\cdot)$ in the dual space, $f(X(\cdot))$ is normal for any $\theta(\cdot)$ in the original function space.

My best (and hopefully correct) try so far is with $-\infty<a<b<\infty$ and restricting $\rho(\cdot)$ to be a non-zero, finite, signed measure with a countable number of mass points.  For the contribution of the mass points at $X(j)$ with measure $d_j$ for $j=1,2,\ldots$, I write $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X(j)d_j$, which is normal for each $n$ (since it's a linear combination of jointly normal random variables) and thus has a normal limit.  Additionally, we need $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\theta(j)d_j<\infty$.  For the rest of the integral, I write it as a Riemann–Stieltjes integral; again, for each finite $n$, it's a linear combination of normals, so the limit is normal, and we just need the limiting mean to be finite (since the limiting variance is assumed finite).

Examples (in the bigger picture): $\theta(\cdot)$ belongs to $L^p$ for $1<p<\infty$, then $\rho(\cdot)$ is such that $d\rho(j)=\rho'(j)\,dj$ where the derivative $\rho'(j)$ is in $L^q$, where $q$ is the Hölder conjugate of $p$ (so $1/p+1/q=1$), and (I think) what I have already is fine.  But if $\theta(\cdot)$ belongs to $C_b(\mathcal{J})$ (continuous and bounded), then the dual space is characterized by $\rho(\cdot)$ being Radon measures, which I think potentially have an **uncountably** infinite number of mass points, which violates my above condition.  But my (uneducated) guess is that countability is not necessary; I just don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

I am also interested in this question. I found the following statement in the paper

- W. Fischer, T. Hupfer, H. Leschke, P. Müller. Existence of the density of states for multi-dimensional continuum Schrödinger operators with Gaussian random potentials. Commun. Math. Phys 190, pp. 133-141, 1997.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a complete probability space and $V : \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, $(\omega , x) \mapsto V^\omega (x)$ be a stationary Gaussian process with mean zero and covariance function $C : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$. They assume that $C$ is continuous at the origin and that $0 < C (0) < \infty$. Let $\mu$ be a finite signed Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Define $\lambda : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$\displaystyle{\lambda (\omega) = N^{-1/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} V^\omega (y) \mu (\mathrm{d} y)}$

where

$\displaystyle{N = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \gamma (x-y) \mu (\mathrm{d} x) \mu (\mathrm{d} y)}$.

They claim that

- the integral in the definition of $\lambda$ is well-defined for $\mathbb{P}$-almost all $\omega \in \Omega$
- $\lambda$ is a random variable
- $\lambda$ is normally distributed with mean zero and variance one.

However, they give no proof of this statement. But if I understand your question correctly, this is exactly what you need, and you have at least a reference now.

I am also very interested in the proof of this claim.

Comment: That's pretty close, although stationarity is a bit stronger than I'd like; I presume "stationary" above means $C(x,y)=\gamma(x-y)$.  But, I upvoted.  Meanwhile, I think I found what I wanted in Definition 2.2.1(ii) on page 42 of V. I. Bogachev's "Gaussian Measures" monograph (1998).

Comment: Yes, this means stationary. I first denoted by $C$ the covariance function, then or some reason I used the symbol $\gamma$, sorry. And thanks for the reference, I will have a look. I also found a nice reference with proofs:

 - J. L. Doob, Stochastic Processes, Wiley, 1990.

See Theorem 2.7 and 2.8 on pages 62 and 64.